# Calculating median for category group AND ignoring missing values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Col A: Categories

Col B: Scores (may have missing data)

What I have so far:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(A$1:A$5="CAT1",B$1:B$5,""))
```

My code groups the columns by category and calculates their median, but fails to ignore missing values- I'm unsure on how to add the <>0 to ignore values; how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `*` to multiply the two Boolean statements:

```
=MEDIAN(IF((A$1:A$5="CAT1")*(B$1:B$5<>0),B$1:B$5,""))
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.